# How do you create a class that does not inherit from Object.prototype using ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, class, null, prototype, ecmascript-6

I can create a class that does not inherit from `Object.prototype` using the older syntax.

```js
function Shape(x, y, width, height) {
  this.x = x,
  this.y = y,
  this.width = width,
  this.height = height;
}

Shape.prototype = Object.create(null, {
  constructor: {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: Shape
  },
  move: {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function (x, y) {
      this.x += x,
      this.y += y;
    }
  }
});

var rect = new Shape(0, 0, 4, 2);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === Shape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect)) !== Object.prototype); //inheritance
```

How can I do this using ES6 classes?

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.width = width,
    this.height = height;
  }

  move(x, y) {
    this.x += x,
    this.y += y;
  }
}

var rect = new Shape(0, 0, 4, 2);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === Shape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect)) === Object.prototype); // inheritance
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `extends null`.

Note the class itself will still inherit from `Function.prototype`, not from `null`. So you will be able to use function methods on the class.

But be aware that, when using an `extends` clause, you must either initialize `this` before using it by calling `super`, or don't use `this` and return an object at the end.

In this case you can't initialize `this` using `super` because `Function.prototype` is not a constructor. So you will have to use `Object.create` to create the object that will become the instance.

```js
class Shape extends null {
  constructor(x, y) {
    // Use `that` instead of `this`, and return it at the end
    var that = Object.create(new.target.prototype);
    that.x = x;
    that.y = y;
    return that;
  }
  move(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  }
}
var rect = new Shape(0, 0);
console.log(rect);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === Shape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape.prototype) === null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape) === Function.prototype);
```

`new.target` will be the function that is being instantiated. This can be `Shape` itself, or another function that extends it. This is useful to allow `Shape` to be extendable.

```js
class Shape extends null {
  constructor(x, y) {
    // Use `that` instead of `this`, and return it at the end
    var that = Object.create(new.target.prototype);
    that.x = x;
    that.y = y;
    return that;
  }
  move(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  }
}
class BestShape extends Shape {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.best = true;
  }
}
var rect = new BestShape(0, 0);
console.log(rect);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === BestShape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(BestShape.prototype) === Shape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape.prototype) === null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(BestShape) === Shape);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape) === Function.prototype);
```

If you don't want to avoid using `this` in your constructor, an alternative is extending a function whose `prototype` is `null`. The downside is that your class will inherit from that function, instead of directly from `Function.prototype`.

```js
function NullClass() {}
NullClass.prototype = null;

class Shape extends NullClass {
  constructor(x, y) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  move(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  }
}
var rect = new Shape(0, 0);
console.log(rect);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === Shape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape.prototype) === null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape) === NullClass);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(NullClass) === Function.prototype);
```

If you don't want to reuse `NullClass`, you can define it inline

```
class Shape extends Object.assign(function(){},{prototype:null}) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: This is interesting! I didn't know you could do this. Good point that doing things this way has the advantage of letting you still use `Function.prototype` methods on `Shape`.

Comment: I read you could `extends null` but could not figure out why `super()` would not work. Thanks for explaining it. That's really wonky though...

Comment: @MichaelTheriot Yes, it doesn't work because `null` is not callable, but it's so annoying. I read they are considering fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to manually set `Shape.prototype`'s prototype to `null`.

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.width = width,
    this.height = height;
  }
    
  move(x, y) {
    this.x += x,
    this.y += y;
  }
}

// This is the key line.
Object.setPrototypeOf(Shape.prototype, null);

const rect = new Shape(0, 0, 4, 2);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === Shape.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(rect)) !== Object.prototype);
```